# How to set a ComboBox's SelectedIndex to zero whenever its ItemsSource changes?

Tags: wpf, styles, master-detail

This should be simple, but I cannot find it:
I have two Comboboxes that are related through a Master-Detail Binding:

```
<ComboBox Style="{StaticResource FixedSelectionCombo}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=ControlRoot, Path=Clubs}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name"
          SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=ControlRoot,Path=SelectedClub}">
</ComboBox>
<ComboBox Style="{StaticResource FixedSelectionCombo}" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=ControlRoot, Path=SelectedClub.PlayerLists}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name"
          SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=ControlRoot, Path=SelectedPlayerList}">
</ComboBox>
```

When I select an item in the first combobox, the second combobox gets populated with the the appropriate PlayerLists, but I want to have its first item selected automatically.

This is easy to do in code behind, but I want to achieve this through a Style that I can put in a ResourceDictionary. I tried:

```
  <Style x:Key="FixedSelectionCombo" TargetType="ComboBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBox}}">
        <Setter Property="SelectedIndex" Value="0"/>
    </Style>
```

But this only works the first time, not after I make a new selection in the first combobox.

How can it be done?

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this by using `Interaction.Triggers`:

```
<ComboBox Style="{StaticResource FixedSelectionCombo}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=ControlRoot, Path=Clubs}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name"
          SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=ControlRoot,Path=SelectedClub}"
          Name="cbClubs">
</ComboBox>
<ComboBox Style="{StaticResource FixedSelectionCombo}" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=ControlRoot, Path=SelectedClub.PlayerLists}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name"
          SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=ControlRoot, Path=SelectedPlayerList}">
     <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged" SourceName="cbClubs">
                <ei:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="SelectedIndex" Value="1"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
     </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ComboBox>
```

Required namespaces:

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" 
xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
```

Comment: I am sorry, this does not work. I get all kinds of error messages that the 'i' namespace does not have this or that. Moreover, the code relies on a hard coded reference to the Master Combobox, which defeats the purpose of using a reusable Style.

Comment: +1, I always forget about interactivity, posting a different solution because I like puzzles :)

Comment: Dabblernl, to make it work you have to add two references 'Microsoft.Expression.Interactions' and 'System.Windows.Interactivity'

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, the best/easiest way to do it is in the ViewModel when SelectedIndex of one changes, flip desired Property (selectedInex of the other) the binding will do the rest.
No need for styles, triggers and the whole mess. But for fun, this was just a quick'n' dirty, so posting the whole/most xaml so it can be copied/pasted/run... using different property names, because I wanted to run/test it first
Note, converter returns a dummy string, on which you can trigger in the style.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
    Title="MainWindow" x:Name="window" >
<Window.Resources>
    <local:IndexConverter x:Key="indexConverter"/>
    <Style x:Key="comboBox2Style">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedList1Item, Converter={StaticResource indexConverter}}" 
                         Value="selectFirstIndexOnAnyPropertyChanged">
                <Setter Property="ComboBox.SelectedIndex" Value="0"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel DataContext="{Binding ElementName=window, Path=ViewModel}">
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding List1}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedList1Item}"/>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding List2}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedList2Item}"
              Style="{StaticResource comboBox2Style}"/>
```

---

```
public class IndexConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return "selectFirstIndexOnAnyPropertyChanged";
    }
```

---

in my code behind created a ViewModel with all the properties List1, List2, SelectedItemList1, etc.. so the bindings would work. Let me know if you need the ViewModel code (omitting it, as obvious..)

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        ViewModel = new ViewModel();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Comment: I appreciate the amount of work you put into this. It demonstrates that implementing this behaviour (reptitively) in the viewmodel or code behind is a lot easier. Still: why is there no simple `ItemsSourceChanged` RoutedEvent that I can make a Trigger on?